# running goharbor behind a reverse proxy

Tags: apache, kubernetes, docker-registry, harbor

Hello i have [harbor](https://goharbor.io/) running perfectly under http://harbor.domain using nginx ingress ,  i install using the harbor-helm chart.

On the terminal i can push helmcharts to http://harbor.domain/chartrepo/,

i am able to login

```
docker login harbor.domain:80
```

and push to the registry.

My challenge is i would like to have harbor be accessed via an apache proxy e.g.

- https://example.com/v2 for the registry
- https://example.com/chartrepo for the chartrepo
- https://example.com/harbor to access the harbor ui

I reinstalled using harbor-helm chart by changing `values.yaml`

```
externalURL: https://example.com
```

So i have then on `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example-le-ssl.conf` i have added the following

```
    # helmcharts 
    <Location "/chartrepo/"> 
          ProxyPass "http://harbor.domain/chartrepo/"
          ProxyPassReverse "http://harbor.domain/chartrepo/"
    </Location>

    # harbor 
    <Location "/harbor"> 
          ProxyPass "http://harbor.domain/harbor"
          ProxyPassReverse "http://harbor.domain/harbor"
    </Location>

    # registry 
    <Location "/v2"> 
          ProxyPass "http://harbor.domain/v2"
          ProxyPassReverse "http://harbor.domain/v2"
    </Location>
```

Unfortunetly if i do `docker login example.com`
docker login returns

```
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://example.com/v2/ failed with status: 503 Service Unavailable
```

i get the following error on the registry logs

```
error authorizing context: authorization token required
```

Any ideas of what is i am missing?

Trying to push a chart also fails.

```
helm push --username='username' --password='password' demo-chart.tgz https://example.com/chartrepo/
```

The error being

```
Error: 404: could not properly parse response JSON: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at example.com Port 443</address>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not able to authorize to the docker registry. Either you can add the variable to default service account or we can create docker registry secret and add that to deployment as imagepullsecret.

If you want to do that from imagepullsecret, you can create a template helper, something like

```
/* image pull secret */
{{- define "imagePullSecret" }}
{{- printf "{\"auths\": {\"%s\": {\"auth\": \"%s\"}}}" .Values.imageCredentials.registry (printf "%s:%s" .Values.imageCredentials.username .Values.imageCredentials.password | b64enc) | b64enc }}
{{- end }}
```

Then you can use that in deployment file like

```yaml
imagePullSecrets:
      - name: {{.Values.imageCredentials.secretName}}
```

Entire file may look like

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.appName }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.appName }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.appName }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Values.appName }}
        image: {{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
        {{- if .Values.hasSecretVolume }}
        volumeMounts:
        - name: {{ .Values.appName }}-volume-sec
          mountPath: {{ .Values.secretVolumeMountPath }}
        {{- end}}
        {{- if or .Values.env.configMap .Values.env.secrets }}
        envFrom:
        {{- if .Values.env.configMap }}
        - configMapRef:
            name: {{ .Values.appName }}-env-configmap
        {{- end }}
        {{- if .Values.env.secrets }}
        - secretRef:
            name: {{ .Values.appName }}-env-secret
        {{- end }}
        {{- end }}
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.containerPort }}
          protocol: TCP
{{- if .Values.springContainerHealthChecks}}
{{ toYaml .Values.springContainerHealthChecks | indent 8 }}
{{- end}}
      {{- if .Values.hasSecretVolume }}
      volumes:
      - name: {{ .Values.appName }}-volume-sec
        secret:
          secretName: {{ .Values.appName }}-volume-sec
      {{- end}}
      {{- if .Values.imageCredentials}}
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: {{.Values.imageCredentials.secretName}}
      {{- end}}
```

Comment: the issue was not crendentials since it was working under harbor.domain.. i figured it out eventually, ill post a longer answer

Answer (score 0):

my first issue was how apache handles proxying to https backend explained here [how to configure apache server to talk to HTTPS backend server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107654/how-to-configure-apache-server-to-talk-to-https-backend-server).

I added to my virtualhost `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example-le-ssl.conf`

```
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
    <Location "/v2"> 
          ProxyPass "http://harbor.domain/v2"
          ProxyPassReverse "http://harbor.domain/v2"
    </Location>
    <Location "/service/">
          # RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
          ProxyPass "http://harbor.domain/service/"
          ProxyPassReverse "http://harbor.domain/service/"
    </Location>
```